# Invoice error when print invoice action call admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, admin-panel, pdf, print

Hello i have created one website magento version 1.9. In admin panel order section when I select any order and select *Print invoices* from action dropdown and submit then got error like:

> "Call to a member function getParentItem() on a non-object in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\charcoal\app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php
>   on line 141";

How can I solved this issues?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable all custom extensions which you have installed into Magento and then try to print invoice. After that, enable extension one by one so you will get idea if any extension conflicts with functionality.

Comment: I already do that but still i get this error. Any custom module for that ?

Comment: Check these links :
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/easy-pdf-invoice.html
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pdf-invoice-1.html

Comment: thanx but its for version 1.8 and i m using 1.9.2.4

Comment: Check these links:

http://www.magestore.com/magento-pdf-invoice-extension.html

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/invoice-pdf-generator.html

Comment: Thanx, let me check