# Call to a member function getParentItem() on a non-object

Tags: orders, sales-order, invoice, sales, print

When I print particular order invoice from sales=>order menu at that time i get error like Call to a member function getParentItem() on a non-object in app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Order\Pdf\Invoice.php on line 145.

Any idea to resolve it ?

Comment: can you place peice of code , which causing this error

Comment: foreach ($invoice->getAllItems() as $item){
                
    if ($item->getOrderItem()->getParentItem()) {
     continue;
                }
                /* Draw item */
                $this->_drawItem($item, $page, $order);
                $page = end($pdf->pages);
            }

Comment: You already asked that question yesterday: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/128056/2380 please ask the same question only once and use the edit feature to add info to your question as it is considered as spam